# ios animatedImageNamed only plays after breakPoint

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an animated image [gif style]

I need to show it in a ViewController that is loaded from a tab,

the image will show the animation if i do a breakPoint after or before calling the image method

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self playDiamond];

    // - Breakpoint
}

- (void)playDiamond
{
    self.diamondView.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"image_diamond-" duration:0.5f];
}
```

SO if i dont use the breakPoint the image will not animate,
if i tap again on the tab bar the image will animate,

how do i make the image animate just by showing my VC?, please note i tried with same result on viewWillAppear / viewDidShow

Comment: What else happens in your code immediately after `[self playDiamond];`? I'd suggest perhaps putting the `animatedImageNamed:` line in a dispatch_async block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
viewDidLoad
```

so that the animation will begin as soon as you show the view controller:

```
diamondView.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"image_diamond-" duration:0.5f];
```

** I've assumed diamondView is a UIImageView **